# How to test how method handles concurrent calls

Tags: java, scala, junit

I have a method and I want to test how it handles concurrent invocations.

Is there a Scala / Java library for this ?

I could use Scala's parallel collections and repeatedly call the method, is this an appropriate method ?

Comment: A plain `ScheduledExecutorService` seems like a very good testing tool all by itself.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik does the ScheduledExecutorService schedule tasks to run on multiple cores ?

Comment: @user470184 Yes, it uses configurable threadpool.

Comment: [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) is an option.

Answer (score 0):

This [post by Gary Gregory](http://garygregory.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/multi-threaded-unit-testing/) seems like it might be addressing what you want to do.